# SSIS Package: Foreach Loop Container within Foreach Loop Container issue

Tags: ssis

I am using a Foreach Loop Container within Foreach Loop Container.  The first FLC reads the Excel files within a folder and then based on the name of file it routes the flow to the next FLC which should load all the data from all tabs in the Excel file.  This is the error I get.

> Error: 0xC0202009 at SSIS_Package, Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 1": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.".

It seems that the issue is with Data Flow Task trying to read from the same file use in the first FLC.  How can this be fixed or can it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the outer ForEach loop using a File Enumerator or is it actually doing something like the ... ado recordset/schema enumerator? The former should not be opening the file at all. What is the Script Task doing? If the Script Task is just an anchor point for the conditional precedent constraints, I find an empty Sequence Container usually named something explicit like "do nothing, anchor point" more intuitive for maintainers.

Comment: Thanks billinkc for your response.  The outer For Each Loop is a File Enumerator and the Script Task is doing nothing just an anchor point for the conditional precedent constraint.  I appreciate your suggestion for the naming.

Comment: So if that's the case, then it would seem that the issue is as the error message states: some person/process has the file open or there's a permission issue. A "dumb hack" that you can try if it's the first, is to copy the file with a new/unique name. Thus Finance.xlsx becomes fjmontes_20240108_Finance.xlsx (or in an entirely new folder). This should allow you to have a "local" copy of the file available for processing without the having to wait for people to get out of the original.